# Replace value between quotes

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to update a `web.config` file, using Jenkins' PowerShell plugin for the following values:

```xml
<add key="SmtpServer1" value="${ SmtpServer1}"/>
<add key="UserID" value="${UserID}"/>
```

where the values are input's into the Jenkins ENV for the buildstep.
For ex. SmtpServer1 input value would be "mail.outbound.xxx.com"  (without the quotes) and UserID input value would be "SteveH".

What I have tried is to use the Jenkins Windows PowerShell buildstep:

```bsh
$SmtpServer1 = "$ENV:SmtpServer1"
$UserID = "$ENV:UserID"
$filename = ".\web.config"

(Get-Content "$filename").Replace('${ SmtpServer1}', "$SmtpServer1") |
    Set-Content "$filename"
(Get-Content "$filename").Replace('${UserID}', "$UserID") |
    Set-Content "$filename"
```

but the output is:

```xml
<add key="mail.outbound.xxx.com" value=""/>
<add key="SteveH" value=""/>
```

What I'd like to get is:

```xml
<add key="SmtpServer1" value="mail.outbound.xxx.com"/>
<add key="UserID" value="SteveH"/>
```

Any direction or ideas?

Comment: Sorry typo's have been updated

Comment: Can you print the variables with `Write-host` and get the data to show up? Code looks Ok at first glance. Perhaps the environment variables are not getting pulled? You have environment variables called SmtpServer1 and UserID?

Comment: So, after jiggering with it a bit, I got it working using the following:     '(Get-Content "$filename").replace('"${ SmtpServer1}"', "$SmtpServer1") | Set-Content "$filename"`        added the double quote inside the single quote

Comment: I don't understand how that fixed the issue since it appeared you were matching correctly but replacing with nothing. Now with what you added in comments you are also matching some quotes as well. I am glad you figured it out I suppose.

Comment: Have you considered using xpath instead of regex?